# Creating iframe by javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a main page that include a javascript that was creating an iframe dynamically same below:

```
<script>
   document.domain = "mydomain.com"

   var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  // creating other element in ifram dynamically 
</script>
```

But in IE I kept receiving a security warning because of document.domain = "mydomain.com" (I need document.domain and I can not remove it).

I found a solution for IE8. this is the solution :

```
var u = 'javascript:(function(){document.open();document.domain="mydomain.com";document.close();})()';
iframe.src = u;
```

But it does not work on IE6. Is there any solution for my problem?

**Note:** I want to create other element in iframe by script and I want to load the content of iframe by src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the iFrame using innerHTML.

Write the full HTML for the iFrame including the SRC attribute. Then find your element and set innerHTML to the string with the iFrame source.